# Finer partitioning of the $[0,1]$ interval

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $S\subset [0,1]$ .

[Lebesgue Density Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem) tells us that the density of $S$ is either $0$ or $1$ almost everywhere on the interval $[0,1]$.

Define a $01$-transition to be a point $x\in [0,1]$ such that $$\exists \epsilon>0:m(S\cap [x-\epsilon,x)\ )=0\ \ \ \wedge\ \ \  m(S\cap (x,x+\epsilon]\ )=1$$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

> Is there such set $S\subset [0,1]$ with **uncountably** infinite number of $01$-transitions?

---

Creating a set with countably infinite transitions is not that complicated:
$$S = \{[2^{-2n-1},2^{-2n}]|n\in \mathbb N\} = [1/2,1] \cup [1/8, 1/4] \cup [1/32,1/16]\ldots$$

While it doesn't seem Lebesgue Theorem denies the existence of set $S$ with uncountably infinite transitions, I'm not sure such exists.

Comment: How do you define a transition?

Comment: A transition is a point $x\in [0,1]$ such that $\exists \epsilon>0:m(S\cap [x-\epsilon,x))=0\wedge m(S\cap (x,x+\epsilon])=1$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. Makes sense?

Comment: If you define it like that, there is always a rational number in any non-trivial interval, so you map those intervals $[x-\epsilon, x)$ and $(x,x+\epsilon]$ to rational numbers, and since rational numbers are countable, there are only countably many transitions. I was asking because in more complicated situations (Cantor sets etc.) there might not be such "clean" transitions, and there could be other ways to define it.

Comment: @LukasGeyer - good point. In fact, that answers my question, so you could turn the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As defined, every transition has an associated left interval where the density is zero and an associated right interval where the density is $1$. These intervals have to be disjoint for different transition points, and each one of them contains at least one rational number, so there can be at most countably many such transitions.

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of the $01$-transition point, we deduce that the set $[0,1]$ has only one $01$-transition point and this point is $0$. For every subset $S \subseteq [0,1]$ there is no $01$-transition point which is different from $0$. Hence answer to  RB's question is no and  each subset $S \subseteq [0,1]$  has no different $01$-transition points  and if $S$ has such a point it  will be unique and equal to $0$.